# What does it mean for two components to be connected?

Tags: architecture, software, networking

It is my impression that in software engineering, a connection can mean many things depending on context and the level of abstraction at which some system is considered. I'm surprised no one has asked this before, as I feel that a *connection* is such a fundamental concept, but also very easy to misunderstand.  I want to wash away any misunderstandings I might have, and thus I ask: What does it mean for two components to be connected? Additionally, how does the view of a connection differ from an software architecture perspective and an implementation perspective?

My current understanding of the concept of "connection" is that two components (or entire systems) have some *agreement* with eachother to exchange data across some interface. This is usually accomplished through initial request from one part, a subsequent process of handshaking, synchronization and eventually some communication *session*.

Comment: Are you trying to define "connection" as new word? Why not use existing words, that better describe what you mean.

Comment: I am merely asking for a clarification of the concept of "connection" in a software engineering perspective. I am familiar with the intuitive meaning of a "connection".

Comment: But you said it yourself! Meaning of "connection" is different based on context. We can't enumerate all different contexts in which "connection" has different meaning.

Comment: I said that it is "my impression" that the meaning of connection means a multitude of things based on context. I was not stating some fact. My question was: "What does it mean for two components to be connected? Additionally, how does the view of a connection differ from an software architecture perspective and an implementation perspective?"

Comment: The first sentence of your understanding I can agree with, but not the second one. If one class has a reference to another class and calls methods on that other class, I would also say that they have a connection.

Comment: Do you mean "connection" as used in "client-server connection", or "database connection"? Not in a general, loose sense of the word?

Comment: That is a good question. I think a client-server connection is what I was originally thinking, and I am not aware of what a database connection is. I understand that my question is quite broad, and I am unsure about how to formulate it in any other way. My main issue is that I have entered a position where I have to understand a lot of technical specifications for a large distributed system, and I do not yet have an understanding of the jargon used by the architects, because there is zero consistency across the documents.

Comment: And here we are discussing *one word* in that jargon, over a period of several hours.  Only 255 words to go.

Comment: If someone shows you a diagram and says "these two things are connected," ***always always always*** make them specify what that means. Is it a dependency diagram? A data flow diagram? Flow of control? Structure? There are lots of meanings and you are right to point out the ambiguity. However your question doesn't have an answer agnostic of context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey every science has its own definitions for everyday words and often progress is only made after *exact* definitions have been agreed upon. Programming as an applied science, in my opinion, is lacking *a lot* in that respect. And the answer given so far seem to justify that point of view.

Comment: @HartmutBraun: Since you weighed in on a question that's over a year old, let me give you my definition of a connection: something that shares data.  That's it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn’t notice the question is so old... anyhow, “sharing some data” is as imprecise as it gets. And that, in my opinion, is a problem. I’m not saying I have the only correct answer (otherwise I would have presented it here). I simply say: agree on a term (that’s a hard thing to do!) and then use it strictly. This hardly ever happens and in my experience a lot of time and money was wasted because of “that’s it”.

Comment: @HartmutBraun: OK, but why is additional precision *for this specific word* required?  If you need a connection, you evaluate the two things your connecting together and come up with a protocol, bus, message queue, stream or some other more specific implementation, and now you're precise.

Comment: In my experience, fledgling software developers have a tendency to focus on the precise meaning of the vocabulary when what they really should be doing is developing a deeper understanding of the principles and techniques underlying said vocabulary.  Just because you know the lingo doesn't mean you understand the subject matter that it embodies.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think OP question was about if there is some general characteristics of something called connection that is independent of protocol, bus, message, stream and the like. Take the REST principle as an example. It is defined completely without any implementation detail and successful exactly for that reason. Admittedly, the word REST was invented, which, hmm...., come to think of it, is maybe better than using an existing word.

Comment: @HartmutBraun: REST is a perfect example of how focusing on vocabulary can go bad.  The prevailing use of the word (as a synonym for CRUD via JSON web services) is not what Roy Fielding had in mind when he coined the term.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm, I was referring to the architectural style. The problem your pointing at is the “then use it strictly” part of my previous comment. Now I see your point: using specific terms doesn’t keep people from using them wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean for two components to be connected?

Let's note that the notion of a live connection between components in two computers, is really just some state held in each computer, that allows protocols to be followed to send bits to each other having desirable intentions and effects.

However, from an architectural point of view regarding two connected components:

In order to understand the connection between components, subsystems, services, client-server, or plain old objects, look to the specific approach used by one component to refer to the other.

The direction of the reference between components gives us the notion of ***dependency***: the referrer is dependent upon the referee.

There are many approaches for reference, some result in tighter coupling than others.

In general, a direct reference uses the ***name*** of the other component, as in a line of code doing `new XYZ()` for objects, or, the direct use of a well-known URL for services, and, such a direct dependency is a tightly coupled connection.

A somewhat more loosely coupled dependency uses an intermediate, though still directly named, such as a factory class for objects, or service locator for services.

Even looser coupling still is the injection approach where a parameter that was supplied during instantiation (or invocation) refers to an abstract capability rather than a directly named component (e.g. interface for objects or abstract service for services).  Typically such components are seen to have a dependency on an abstraction rather than on another (concrete) component.  The actual dependencies between concrete components are configured externally to the connected components.

Another aspect of connection is mutual dependency, where one component is *directly dependent* upon another and vice versa (i.e. the latter is *directly dependent* upon the former); this is often considered bad form as it leads to ordering issues and problems in instantiation and tear down.  (In order to avoid cyclic dependencies, one or both components can use an approach of looser coupling, though this can be a difficult refactoring if such technical debt has been accruing for long.)

> Additionally, how does the view of a connection differ from an software architecture perspective and an implementation perspective?

Architectural points of view often abstract out certain details in order to reason about some particular aspect of the system.  For example, we might speak of a hard coded URL in one component referring to another component.  This description ignores the DNS lookup that provides a level of indirection.

Another way they might differ is: Let's say an implementation uses an injection oriented approach, and that it is a data driven approach to configuration, where the data is supplied in a configuration file.  Such an approach allows for changes between versions of the software, though for any given version, we might take an architectural point of view of the system that ignores the reconfigure-ability and looks at the interactions of components we know will be configured a certain way in this version.

> My current understanding of the concept of "connection" is that two components (or entire systems) have some agreement with each other to exchange data across some interface. This is usually accomplished through initial request from one part, a subsequent process of handshaking, synchronization and eventually some communication session.

The handshaking & eventual transfer of data you're describing can be thought of as protocol, and applies to services, though in some sense can also be applied to objects and their APIs where certain things have to happen before others.  Also relevant are the terms contract and abstraction, in addition to interface.  These are various terms used to describe those prearranged agreements to exchange information using interfaces.  These things happen and can be described many levels, e.g. wire protocols: TCP, REST APIs (the meaning of a single GET or POST vs. the collection and formation of query strings), document schemas for query results, etc...

Still, key to the notion of connection between components is the approach to how one component initially locates and identifies another component, as this is the essential element of the formation of connection from an architectural point of view, which goes to the above discussion on dependency and coupling, e.g. direct naming vs. service locator, vs. injection, or other, and from the implementation point of view, these connections and types of connections are manifest in specific ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are some major vagaries in your question that require some disambiguation:

- **Definition of component:** there are different types of components that have their own concept of connections and interdependencies

  - External components (aka Services) -- whether we are talking micro-services or monolithic ones, the services have some sort of wire protocol between them.  That wire protocol can be a REST API, a message queue, or even a proprietary data protocol
  - Internal components -- this is simply a way of organizing code so that you reduce code coupling and isolate unrelated parts of the application from each other.  Most often they call each other directly
- **Connection or Dependency?**  often in computer science, the concept of a connection is synonymous with a wire protocol.  I don't want to speak in absolutes here, but I can't come up with any examples where connection does not mean a wire protocol is involved.  The more generic concept is a dependency.

The specifics of your answer depend on your audience and what scope you are referring to.

> What does it mean for two components to be connected?

The correct terminology is that one component has a **dependency** on another component.  The *consumer* component (the one with the dependency) will make calls to the *producer* component (the component depended on).  The producer component will have a defined interface that is shared publicly.  The consumer component only interacts with the interface, allowing the implementation to be replaced without breaking the system.

> Additionally, how does the view of a connection differ from an software architecture perspective and an implementation perspective?

The concept of a dependency is an architectural concern.  The concept of a connection (i.e. wire protocol) is an implementation concern.  Connections are not always needed (i.e. the internal context).

I think you are merging concepts in your mind that really are separate things and that is what is confusing.

Comment: A "connection" is the implementation manifestation of the architectural concept of "dependency". As explained quite well in this answer. However, it's focused on some components (classes and whole systems.) A function is also a component.

A function that requires a value and returns a value is dependent on something else to provide the required value and when you write the code that calls the function by providing the value, you are also implementing a dependency by establishing a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Having reviewed the existing answers, I'd like to suggest an alternative: components that are "connected" are those that are under a common management.

By management I mean the oversight and control of the person who designs the system. "Connected" components are those that are being made to work together for some purpose, by the management.

In my view neither component needs to be "dependent" on the other. They may be completely severable and still function independently.

It's the system as a whole, and the purpose it is designed to fulfil, which is dependent on the connection. That is, the dependency exists between the purpose, on the one hand, and the arrangement of components, on the other.